# JqGrid doesn't close form edit after reloadGrid triggered

Tags: jqgrid

:-)
I think I encountered probably a bug on jqGrid 5.8.3 js I am using, but I am not sure…I wrote this code to refresh grid after submit the formedit:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
jQuery(this).jqGrid(‘editGridRow’,
rowid,
{
editCaption: “Update”,
recreateForm:true,
dataheight: 180,
height: 270,
width: 350,
top: 40,
left: 170,
onclickSubmit : function (options, postdata) {
if( confirm(‘Update this record (Y/N)?’) ) {
//var rowid = postdata[this.id];
console.log( JSON.stringify(postdata) );
return {
// myParam: $(this).jqGrid(“getCell”, rowid, “URL”)
// test : “bla bla”
returndata : JSON.stringify( postdata )
//returndata : postdata
};
}
},
errorTextFormat: function (data) {
return ‘Error: ‘ + data.responseText
},
closeOnEscape: true,
closeAfterEdit: true,
afterSubmit : function() { $(“#grd-points_registry”).jqGrid(‘setGridParam’,{datatype:’json’}).trigger(‘reloadGrid’); }
//reloadAfterSubmit: false,
//aftersavefunc : function() { setTimeout( function() { $(“#grd-points_registry”).trigger(“reloadGrid”); }, 10); }
}
);
}
```

since I found searching on the web about .trigger(‘reloadGrid’) to force reloading after edit/add but the editform won’t close after triggered the reloadGrid thing and in debug on Chrome I see this:

```
jquery.jqGrid.min.js?ver=5.8.3:652 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘0’)
at Object.complete (jquery.jqGrid.min.js?ver=5.8.3:652:172)
at fire (jquery.js?ver=3.6.0:3500:31)
at Object.fireWith (jquery.js?ver=3.6.0:3630:7)
at done (jquery.js?ver=3.6.0:9811:21)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=3.6.0:10057:9)
```

but all fields are numbers in this case …. same thing occurs also on edit and add inside navgrid pager…. any idea?

Thanks! Cheers!

Luigino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do reloadGrid in afterSubmit, since the grid do reloading automatically after the data is posted to the server. In your case you do two reloading one after other which causes unexpected behavior

Actually reloading in form editing is option and you can disable and enable it. By default the reloading is on.

In your case I suggest you to set Json datatype in onclickSubmit event (if no errors) and not reload the grid, since the parameter is set and when  you submit the data it is reloaded (because of json datatype already).

I highly recommend you first to read the docs.